# how to replace one list item with another with jquery

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

I have the following list of forms:

```
<ul class="form-list">
<li>
     <div class="my-display">
          <h1>form 1</h1>
          <form method="POST" action="" id="my-form">
               <button id="button_id" type="submit" class="btn" >Submit</button>
          </form>
     </div>
</li>
<li>
     <div class="my-display">
          <h1>form 2</h1>
          <form method="POST" action="">
               <button id="button_id" type="submit" class="btn" >Submit</button>
          </form>
     </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

I create the list items dynamically and return them with ajax.  I want to click the button and have the list item replaced with the new list item that is returned with ajax.

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.form-list').on('submit', '#my-form', function (e) {

                var id = $(this).attr('name');
                getListItem(getListItemCallback, id); 

                return false;
            });

          });


getListItem(callback, id){          
    $.get(url, function(result) {                    
        callback(result);
        return false;

        });
 }

getListItemCallback:function(result){

 }
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What do you actually get in your `result` variable, HTML mark-up `<li>Some list-item content</li>` or just a string `Some list-item content` that needs to be wrapped in an `li` and then used to replace the current `li`?

Comment: use [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

Comment: ok added more of what I am doing with the form

Comment: I get the actual markup between each <li>list item</li> above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first place, since you are using AJAX, there is no need for the out-dated `<form>` POST method. AJAX will do that quite nicely.

*Note that I added unique IDs to your DIVs and buttons.*

Next, when the user clicks a SUBMIT button, use jQuery DOM traversal selectors (e.g. .find, .next, .prev, .closest, .parent, etc) to find the ID of the DIV to which the button belongs. I used .parent() to get "this" div's ID.

**All DIVs (and buttons) should have unique IDs.**

I recommend using the $.ajax() format because it is more structured than .get() or .post() and therefore easier to troubleshoot.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('.btn').click(function() {
                    my_butt = $(this).attr('id');
                    my_div = $(this).parent().attr('id');
                    //alert('Button: ' +my_butt+ '     DIV: ' + my_div);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "your_php_file.php",
                        data: 'myDiv=' +my_div+ '&theButton=' +my_butt,
                        success: function(whatigot) {
                            alert('Server-side response: ' + whatigot);
                            //$("'#" +my_div+ "'").html(whatigot);
                            $("#"+my_div).html(whatigot);
                        } //END success fn
                    }); //END $.ajax

                }); //END btn class click

            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <ul class="form-list">
    <li>
         <div id="li-1" class="my-display">
              <h1>form 1</h1>
               <button id="button_id-1" type="submit" class="btn" >Submit</button>
         </div>
    </li>
    <li>
         <div id="li-2" class="my-display">
              <h1>form 2</h1>
               <button id="button_id-2" type="submit" class="btn" >Submit</button>
         </div>
    </li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

**your_php_file.php**

```
<?php

    $d = $_POST['myDiv'];
    $b = $_POST['theButton'];

    $r = '<h1>Received Data:</h1>';
    $r .= 'Div Name: ' .$d. '<br />';
    $r .= 'ButtonID: ' .$b. '<br />';

    echo $r;
```

Comment: i did it with a list id, but yeah